# Error when trying to implement agenda list for react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to use `AgendaList` to show the tasks for the day of the calendar selected that is created. However this error is thrown:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...section of this.props.sections...')

This error is located at:

    in VirtualizedSectionList (created by SectionList)
    in SectionList (created by AgendaList)
    in AgendaList (created by CalendarScreen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CalendarProvider)
    in CalendarProvider (created by CalendarScreen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CalendarScreen)
    in CalendarScreen (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Screen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreenNavigationContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by TabNavigator)
    in TabNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by AuthNavigator)
```

My code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Agenda, AgendaList, CalendarProvider, ExpandableCalendar } from 'react-native-calendars';
import { Card, Avatar } from 'react-native-paper';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs, addDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

// const timeToString = (time) => {
//   const date = new Date(time);
//   return date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
// };

const timeToString = (time) => {
  const date = new Date(time);
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
};


const theme = {
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  calendarBackground: '#ffffff',
  textSectionTitleColor: '#b6c1cd',
  selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#478C5C',
  selectedDayTextColor: '#ffffff',
  todayTextColor: '#478C5C',
  dayTextColor: '#2d4150',
  textDisabledColor: '#999999',
  arrowColor: '#478C5C',
};

const firebaseConfig = {
  -
};

const CalendarScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState({});
  const [subtitle, setSubtitle] = useState('');

  const navigateToAddTaskScreen = () => {
    navigation.navigate('AddTask');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getFirestore(app);
  
    const fetchTasks = async () => {
      try {
        const tasksSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'tasks'));
        const tasksData = tasksSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        //console.log('Tasks data:', tasksData);
        
        //stores the tasks categorised by selected day
        const newItems = {};
    
        tasksData.forEach((task) => {
          const selectedDay = timeToString(task.time);
    
          if (newItems[selectedDay]) {
            newItems[selectedDay].push({
              name: task.name,
              // description: task.description,
              // time: task.time,
            });
          } else {
            newItems[selectedDay] = [
              { 
                name: task.name,
                // description: task.description,
                // time: task.time,
              },
            ];
          }
        });
    
        //console.log('New items:', newItems);
        setItems(newItems);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching tasks: ', error);
      }
    };
    fetchTasks();    
  }, []);
  
  const loadItems = (day) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const selectedDay = timeToString(day.timestamp);
      // console.log('Selected day:', selectedDay);

      const selectedItems = items[selectedDay] || [];
      // console.log('Selected items:', selectedItems);

      const sortedItems = selectedItems.sort((a, b) => {
        return new Date(a.time) - new Date(b.time);
      });

      const newItems = {
        [selectedDay]: sortedItems,
      };
      //console.log('New items:', newItems);

      setItems(newItems);
  
      const selectedDate = new Date(selectedDay);
      const month = selectedDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
      const year = selectedDate.getFullYear();
      const formattedSubtitle = `${month} ${year}`;
      setSubtitle(formattedSubtitle); // Add this line to update the subtitle state
    }, 1000);
  };

  const list = [{
    "description": "-",
    "name": "2",
    "time": "2023-05-26T02:01:29.111Z",
  }] 

  const deleteTask = (item) => {
    const selectedDay = timeToString(Date.now());
    const newItems = { ...items };
    const tasks = newItems[selectedDay];
    const updatedTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.time !== item.time);
    newItems[selectedDay] = updatedTasks;
    setItems(newItems);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    if (!item) { //|| !item.name || !item.description || !item.time
      //console.log('Invalid item:', item);
      return null; // Return early if item or required properties are missing
    }
  
    //console.log('Rendering item:', item);
  
    return (
      <Agenda.Item
        key={item.time}
        onPress={() => console.log('Item pressed:', item)}
        style={{ marginRight: 10, marginTop: 17 }}
      >
        <Card>
          <Card.Content>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
            >
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Avatar.Text label="J" />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => deleteTask(item)}>
                  <Text style={{ color: 'red', marginLeft: 8 }}>Delete</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>
      </Agenda.Item>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Task</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitleText}>{subtitle}</Text>
      </View>
      <CalendarProvider
        date={new Date()}
        onDateChanged={(date) => loadItems(date)}
      >
        <ExpandableCalendar
          initialPosition={ExpandableCalendar.positions.CLOSED}
          theme={theme}
        />
        <AgendaList
          // data={Object.entries(items)}
          sections={items}
          renderItem={renderItem}
        />
      </CalendarProvider>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addButton} onPress={navigateToAddTaskScreen}>
        <Text style={styles.addButtonLabel}>Add Task</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff', // Set the background color to white
  },
  headerContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  subtitleText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginLeft: 8,
    color: 'gray',
  },
  taskInputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  taskInput: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: '#cccccc',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginRight: 8,
  },
  addButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#478C5C',
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  addButtonLabel: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  dayContainer: {
    width: 36,
    height: 36,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: '#478C5C',
  },
});


export default CalendarScreen;
```

Comment: You might want to read [mre] and concentrate on the *minimal* part. You've posted a whole bunch of code, but very little textual description for us to go on as to what might cause the error.